# Condensed/liquid vector spaces and path integrals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, condensed-mathematics, feynman-integral, path-integral

[Edited to take into account comments.]

**Background**

One approach to the problem of making rigorous various measures on spaces of paths (for example, the Wiener or Feynman measure) is the time-slicing approach. From what I understand of this approach, one essentially considers measures on the simpler space of piecewise linear continuous functions and hopes that taking finer and finer "lattice" lengths gives a well-defined limit for the integral.

Consider,for instance, the set $Cont_{2^d}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)$ of piecewise linear paths which break only at coordinates of the domain in the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}[1/2^d]$. This is a $n\cdot(2^d+1)$-dimensional space. By forgetting every other break point and interpolating, we get a map $Cont_{2^d} \to Cont_{2^{d-1}}$ and these spaces form a natural inverse system. Likewise, we have inclusions $Cont_{2^{d-1}} \to Cont_{2^{d}}$.

This sort of profinite limit structure makes me think of condensed sets as developed by Clausen and Scholze. Indeed, one can look at the above objects as condensed sets and then take the limit and colimit of these inverse and directed systems. We can call the resulting condensed vector spaces $LimCont_{2^\infty}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)$ and $ColimCont_{2^\infty}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)$.

The Stone-Weierstrauss theorem says that the inclusion $$ColimCont_{2^\infty} \to Cont([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)$$ is dense. As Scholze has recently indicated in an answer on this site, such inclusions are an interesting application of the condensed formalism.

One also has the map $$Cont([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n) \to LimCont_{2^\infty}$$ given by sampling at points in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2^d]$

**Question**

1. What can one say about the quotient $$Cont([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)/ColimCont_{2^\infty}$$ in the category of condensed sets? What about the quotient $$LimCont_{2^\infty}/Cont([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)?$$
2. Can the theory of condensed/liquid vector spaces be used to construct or extend measures on the spaces $Cont([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)$, $LimCont_{2^\infty}$, or $ColimCont_{2^\infty}$?
3. Related insights are welcome.

I apologize in advance if I've made any functional analysis blunders here. Not my specialty, as you can see! Thanks all.

Comment: At the risk of being a nitpicking analyst -- not even a functional analyst, just a basic analyst -- your definition of ${\rm Cont}_{2^d}([0,1], {\bf R}^n)$ seems to say that the breakpoints of these functions need not be at multiples of $2^{-d}$. But in that case I don't see why this would be a vector space, just consider $d=1$ and try to add two functions whose breakpoints are at different points

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point because I don't know about condensed things, but isn't the natural map supposed to go *to* the inverse limit (i.e. you sample your continuous function at 2^d points and get a PL approximation)? I can't imagine a map going the other way (e.g. you could have a sequence of sawtooth PL maps which get wigglier and wigglier and don't define anything continuous in the limit)

Comment: Even if you fix the breakpoints in multiples of $2^{-d}$, I don't see the map $Cont_{2^d} \to Cont_{2^{d-1}}$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I think maybe it is the map that takes the interpolation of $f: \{0,\frac{1}{2},1\}\to \mathbb{R}$ and returns the interpolation of $f|\{0,1\}$, i.e. it retains the property of being piecewise affine, but "forgets that the midpoint exists"

Comment: Thanks, folks--will edit to account for these comments.

Comment: And yes, that was the idea of the limit map.

Comment: In which category do you want to take the limit and colimit?

Comment: The category of condensed vector spaces was what I had in mind.